# How do I make the top portion of my page remain a different color than the body even when I zoom-in or out?

Tags: html, zooming, background-color

I've seen similar questions to do this but so far I can't find any that address the obvious. On my website the top portion is a different color than the body which I created using a div and setting a color to that div. Two simple questions.

How do I get that div to fill the entire portion of the header of the screen regardless if I zoom in or out?

And how do I keep my title and menu bar from falling out when I zoom-in the browser?

I have gotten close so many times but there is always a compromise. Either the div fills the entire header but when I zoom in the text falls out and causes the div to wrap around the page or the menu wraps and it's just gotten frustrating. I hope what I wrote made sense but if not here is a clear example of what I want to accomplish. http://carlodiego.businesscatalyst.com/index.html#home 
Notice on this page that if you zoom in or out the top portion remains filled with the same color.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get that div to fill the entire portion of the header of the
>   screen regardless if I zoom in or out?

simply make the add css with `width:100%` &&  `margin:auto`

Comment: thanks but read the rest of my question. I was able to figure that part out but when add text to the child divs it creates problems.

Comment: could you explain more the rest of your question or post jsfiddle example of your problem?

Comment: http://carlodiego.businesscatalyst.com/index.html#home  ...notice how the header stays in place and when you zoom out it still takes the entire width of the screen? This requires much more than just simply width: 100%